# Compress videofiles from context menu in Windows 11 using ffmpeg

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg, directory, registry

I'd looking for an easy way to just right click on a folder in Windows and be able to loop through video files and compress them with ffmpeg with prepared command settings.

Been able to prepare the reg file to import but I think I'm missing something important here (working directory reference I think). How should I pass the working dir path inside a command like that for this mechanism to work?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\Compress_videos]
@="Compress videos"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\Compress_videos\command]
@="cmd /c for \"%E\" in (.mp4, .mkv, .mov, .avi) do forfiles /m *\"%E\" /c \"cmd /c C:\\Windows\\System32\\ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -y -hwaccel cuda -i @path -c:v hevc_nvenc -b:v 8000k -c:a copy @fname_compressed.mp4\""
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through and do like you want. (Warning: I didn't test it.)

```
cmd /c for %E in (.mp4, .mkv, .mov, .avi) do forfiles /m *%E /c "cmd /c ffmpeg -i \"@file\" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a aac -b:a 128k \"@fname.mp4\""
```

Comment: Does not work when launched from folder's context menu. Sure it will do the job when run from cmd (mine does as well) but that wasn't the case, was it.

Comment: the % symbols in the for command need to be escaped if the command is run from a batch file or script. You can do this by replacing each % symbol with a %% symbol. if that isn't the problem then its the environment your running it in with different privileges.